# Pandas: Show entire rows without truncation

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-sns

I have a python script that sends off an email on failure using AWS SNS. I'm having an issue where the dataframe gets truncated, and I'm not sure how to show the entire thread. I have tried using the pandas `set_option` but that does not seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to print out the entire dataframe and show the entire row?

Here is a small snippet of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

session = boto3.Session()
sns = session.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')

d = {'failed_runs':['296e62fb-1bc2-4e27-8d69-4a2267237698 - FAILED-GSN-INTO', '92b15078-1fcc-41f0-bc20-d933becf23bf - FAILED-ESP2-INTO', 'b04460ef-32a7-403a-8fbe-468effed7f2b - FAILED-HLN-INTO']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

response = sns.publish(TopicArn="arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxxx",
                       Message="""
        Daily Digest for Failed Runs
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        {}

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        """.format(df))
```

This gives me an email like:

```
       Daily Digest for Failed Runs
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                                  failed_runs
0   296e62fb-1bc2-4e27-8d69-4a2267237698 - FAILED-...
1   92b15078-1fcc-41f0-bc20-d933becf23bf - FAILED-...
2   b04460ef-32a7-403a-8fbe-468effed7f2b - FAILED-...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me:

```
#unlimited width - None
In [41]: pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
                                               failed_runs
0   296e62fb-1bc2-4e27-8d69-4a2267237698 - FAILED-GSN-INTO
1  92b15078-1fcc-41f0-bc20-d933becf23bf - FAILED-ESP2-INTO
2   b04460ef-32a7-403a-8fbe-468effed7f2b - FAILED-HLN-INTO

#reset to default width
In [43]: pd.reset_option('max_colwidth')

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
                                         failed_runs
0  296e62fb-1bc2-4e27-8d69-4a2267237698 - FAILED-...
1  92b15078-1fcc-41f0-bc20-d933becf23bf - FAILED-...
2  b04460ef-32a7-403a-8fbe-468effed7f2b - FAILED-...
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try to print the df into the output instead of using {}.format(df)

```
print(df.to_string())
```